# CR Touch install help

Tags: creality-ender-3, troubleshooting, bltouch

I bought my son an Ender 3 Pro and a CR touch. I am trying to get this setup to print for him despite having zero experience with 3D printing and at a loss with the installation.

Here are the details:

- I have the 4.2.2 motherboard.
- I have reviewed my CR Touch install and believe it to be correct.
- I did the formatting of my SD card.
- I have downloaded and installed this firmware: `Ender-3pro_HW4.2.2_SW2.0.8.27_CRTOUCH.bin`.
- I am having the "homing failed message".
- When I try to move the Z-axis, nothing happens (the printer sits idle).
- I have read about adding the G-code however have no idea where to do this.

When I power the unit on, something doesn't seem right. I have read the provided install directions, searched Youtube videos, and read through this site to no avail. I just need somebody with some experience here to help walk me through getting this setup.

I did not use the printer prior to the CR Touch install.

Comment: Have you tried the [CR Touch Install Guide – Complete Walkthrough!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b3r0t7PvbHc) YouTube video?

Comment: @agarza Although the video explain the hardware and software adjustments to get a sensor working it also shows us why you shouldn't buy an Ender 3... Look at the XZ gantry when the sensor hits the surface OMG, left is going down and right not... Not a very good instructional video to promote touch sensors on the Ender 3.

Comment: Can you make the basic Ender 3 work without installing the touch? If not, the problem is likely on that side.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many pre-compiled versions of firmware available of which some don't work well and others are labeled incorrectly or not enough.

For this reason many people compile their own files; you are in control of the options of your choice. But, building your own firmware requires some skills, so it is imaginable that some like to use pre-compiled files.

Another compiled file you could try is [this one](https://img.staticdj.com/071ca474f52dd0d51a802d45efdb9540.zip):

> In this file- Firmwares of CR Touch for Ender-3 Pro Series with 32-bit motherboard. Before update any firmwares, please refer to ["CR Touch Firmware Version for 32-bit Motherboard"](https://img.staticdj.com/9492bcf1d6457b681a6ae305c4bed148.pdf?spm=..product_ca58ac35-a13e-45c9-9863-ffb9220605c5.download_support_2.1&spm_prev=..search.search_1.1) for more details on how to select firmwares.

According to the latter link, you require firmware file "Ender-3pro_HW4.2.2_SW2.0.8.27_CRTOUCH", so you should have the correct version! But, there appears to be a consensus to [**not use** Creality pre-compiled](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ender3Pro/comments/xfbk2p/question_for_updating_firmware_for_cr_touch/) firmware! It appears that the firmware doesn't work (well).